# MySQL Query - WHERE and IF?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, pdo

SOLVED:
Datatypes in the table for country and OS were set to VARCHAR so in my where, I changed = 0 to = '0'.
Thanks to raina77ow for pointing this out! Appreciate it.

I'm not quite sure how to write this query. Basically, I'm going to have a table with two columns (OS and country_code) - more columns too, but those are the conditional ones. These will be either set to 0 for all, or specific ones, separated by commas.

Now, what I'm trying achieve is pull data from the table if the OS and country_code = 0, or if they contain matching data (separated by commas).

Then, I have a column for time. I want to select rows where the time is GREATER than the time column, unless the column time_t is set to false, in which case this shouldn't matter.

I hope I explained it right?

This is what I kind of have so far:

```
$get = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM commands 
    WHERE country_code = 0 OR country_code LIKE :country_code 
    AND OS = 0 OR OS LIKE :OS 
    AND IF (time_t = 1, expiry > NOW())
");
$get->execute(array(
    ':country_code' => "%{$data['country_code']}%",
    ':OS' =>  "%{$data['OS']}%"
));
```

EDIT: This is the code I'm using now, but I still can't seem to get the OS and Country_code part working:

```
$get = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM commands 
WHERE (country_code = 0 OR country_code LIKE :country_code) 
AND (OS = 0 OR OS LIKE :OS) 
AND (time_t <> 1 OR expiry > NOW())
");

$get->execute(array(
':country_code' => "%{$data['country_code']}%",
':OS' =>  "%{$data['OS']}%"
));
```

Data sent to the DB would be: 
OS => Windows 7 
country_code => GB 
ONLY one would be being sent, not more than one. The issue I'm having right now is, it's working for OS and for the time thing, but it's not working for the country. I even tried a raw query, when the data in the table is "FR, SA" and I did LIKE '%GB%' it still returned the row

Comment: Why are you using `LIKE` everywhere ?

Comment: Because, if the OS or country_code != 0, then it'll contain data like "GB, US, FI" and I want to check if it's in there. :)

Comment: That would mean that you have much deeper issue. You table structure is broken. What you have do is covered in first chapter of [SQL Antipatterns](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns) book. Instead you should have separate table for `CountryCodes` and junction table `CommandCountryCodes` to handle the many-to-many relationship between them. And same goes for `OS` column.

Comment: @tereško Your comment deserves to be an answer. )

Comment: I see. This could get tedious having numerous tables for just a single command. Do you think there would be another way of doing this?

Comment: Actually what i suggested is accordance with [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form). And, in your case, this would both improve the database logic and make the queries work much faster. Also, I strongly recommend for you to get the above mentioned book. Steal it, buy it, borrow it .. I don't care, just read it.

Comment: @raina77ow , lets say i have a bit higher standards for what answer should be =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a question of logical operators' precedence: `AND` is higher than `OR` in the ladder, so your original query will be executed as...

```
WHERE country_code = 0 OR (country_code LIKE ... AND OS = 0) OR OS LIKE...
```

Use parenthesis to separate your conditions, like this:

```
WHERE (country_code = 0 OR country_code LIKE ...) 
  AND ( OS = 0 OR OS LIKE ...)
```

And the final filter condition in this query, I suppose, should be written as...

```
AND ( time_t <> 1 OR expiry > NOW() )
```

UPDATE: ... and it's actually should be `country_code = '0'` or something like this in your code. You're checking the VARCHAR column, remember.

Comment: Right. Okay. Country code will either be 0 or data like "GB" or data like "GB, US, NI" -- OS will be pretty much the same as above.

I only want rows pulled if BOTH conditions are met. If that makes any sense?

Comment: I'm talking not about data in DB - I'm talking about the query. As the query obviously is what fails. So I'd like to know what _exactly_ is sent to the DB, which strings are bound to the query. It cannot be '%GB, US, NI%', right?

Comment: It would be great if you give an example of the row that is wrongly returned by the query, too.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Okay, data sent to the DB would be:
OS => Windows 7
country_code => GB

ONLY ever one would be being sent, not more than one.

The issue I'm having right now is, It's working for OS and for the time thing, but it's not working for the country. I even tried a raw query, when the data in the table is "FR, SA" and I did LIKE '%GB%' it still returned the row.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13555/discussion-between-raina77ow-and-prash)

Comment: Got your message; that worked perfectly, thank you very much!